# Read Folder Contents in Chrome Application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have an application which outputs text files periodically with data in it. The text files are initiated from within the application and a datetime/context sensitive name -- though always output to the same folder. I would like to write a chrome application that can watch the folder these files are output to, read them, parse them, and then display them in a friendly manner.

However, there does not seem to be any obvious way to get the contents of a folder in a chrome app. I've read suggestions to use an NPAPI plugin, but it appears those are being [phased out](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi). NACL seems like it might do it but I've also read that it doesn't have full access to the file-system.

Is this something that can even be done? Reading the contents of an arbitrary folder from a packaged chrome application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs: [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)

Chrome Apps can access a directory (after getting the user to select it once) and periodically poll it. Unfortunately, there seems to be no event-based approach to watch a folder for changes.

You should check out the [HTML5Rocks tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir) on HTML5 Filesystems. Ignore the abandoned standard warning: yes, it's only supported in Chrome, but Chrome APIs rely on it and it's not going away.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked the openDirectory option on [choose entry](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-chooseEntry)