# Unable to Browse Local Directory after Deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory

```
 List<string> destDir1 = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(paths, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                               .Where(f => Regex.IsMatch(f, @"[\\/]\d+$"))
                               .ToList();

grdtestcases.DataSource = destDir1.Select(path => new DirectoryInfo(path));
grdtestcases.DataBind();
```

Hi i am using the above code to browse the folders inside the path. But it works fine locally. When i deployed the application on IIS. Not it takes the server folders instead of local machine folder. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: To be clear, when you run it on IIS do you want to search the folders on the IIS server or the user's desktop?

Comment: I have deployed the web application on IIS Server.
Now i am browing the files from my pc but it gives me folders inside the IIS Server location.
I want in User's Desktop

Answer (score 0):

The web server simply cannot browse the directories on the user's desktop.

You could do it using JavaScript in the browser, but it will require some user interaction.  For security web pages are normally run in a "sandbox" to isolate them from the host computer, so the any file system access has to be initiated by the user.

This Stack Overflow question provides some more details: [Read Folder Contents in Chrome Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245931/read-folder-contents-in-chrome-application)

Comment: I am using Browse Directory to get the Local system files.. But it is also showing server files.

Comment: But the code is running on the server - it cannot know anything about the client.

Comment: Is there any other way to browse files inside a folder for client location?

Comment: The link I provided gives one solution (for Chrome only), but it can only be used by code running in the browser - the server known nothing about the client.  If you have control over the server and the client you could potentially set up an FTP service on the client, but I can't think of many cases where this would make sense.